# Format ultimate datatable row according to field status in Angular

Tags: angularjs, datatable

I am using ultimate datatables in angular views. I have a model named Users, which has a field named status (boolean): 1 means blocked and 0 unblocked. All databases rows are shown in UsersHomeView, including Status field. I need that all rows whose Status field contains 1 (users that are blocked) use a different CSS format and appear colored in red. 
I've searched about ultimate datatables but not enough info is available.
Here is my UserHomeController:

```
define(['app', 'u_datatables'], function (app) {
    app.controller('UserHomeController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', 'datatable',
        function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http, datatable) {
            $scope.formData = {};

            var datatableConfig = {
                "name": "simple_datatable",
                "columns": [

                    {
                        "header": "Alias",
                        "property": "user",
                        "type": "text",
                    },


                     {
                        "header": "Nombre",
                        "property": "name",
                        "type": "text",
                    },
                     {
                        "header": "Email",
                        "property": "email",
                        "type": "email",
                    },
                   {
                        "header": "Estado",
                        "property": "status",
                        "type": "boolean",
                         "edit":true,
                    },

                     {
                        "header": "Tipo",
                        "property": "type",
                        "type": "checkbox",

                    },
                    {
                        "header": "Rol",
                        "property": "role",
                        "type": "text",

                    }



                ],
                    "edit":{
                    "active":true,
                    "columnMode":true
                },
                "filter": {
                    "active": true,
                    "highlight": true,
                    "columnMode": false
                },
                "pagination": {
                    "mode": 'local',
                    "bottom": true,
                    "numberRecordsPerPageList": [{
                        number: 10,
                        clazz: ''
                    }, {
                        number: 25,
                        clazz: ''
                    }]
                },
                "order": {
                    "mode": 'local'
                },
                "remove": {
                    "active": true,
                    "mode": 'remote',
                    "url": function (value) {
                        return '/api/users/' + value.id;
                    }
                },

    "edit" : {
    "active":true,//Active or not
    "withoutSelect":false, //edit all line without selected it                              
    "showButton":true,//Show the edit button in the toolbar
    "showLineButton": false, // Show the edit buttons left of each line
    "columnMode":true,//Edit column
    "byDefault":false, //Set in edit mode when the datatable is build
    "lineMode":function(line){ return boolean;} //function used to define if line is editable
},
                "compact": true,
                "hide": {
                    "active": true,
                    "byDefault": [
                       // "address",
                       // "description"
                    ]
                },
                "show" : {
                    "active":true,
                    "showButton":true,
                    "add":function(user){
                        $location.url('/User?id=' + user.id);
                    }
                },
                "select":{
                    "active":true,//Active or not
                    "showButton":true,//Show the select all button in the toolbar,
                },
                "mouseevents": {
                    "active": true,
                    "clickCallback": function (line, data) {
                        console.log("callback select : " + data.name);
                    }
                }
            };

            //GET ALL USERS
            $http.get('/api/users').then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.users = response.data;

                $scope.datatable = datatable(datatableConfig);
                $scope.datatable.setData($scope.users);
            });

        }])

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a specific css class for a tr attribute using config.lines.trClass which can be a function with value.data as first parameter, then you can check if status is 1 or 0 and return your css class.

`var datatableConfig = {
   name = "asdfad"
   ...
   lines = {
      trClass = function(value.data, value.line) {
          return some css class
      }
}`

link to source code: https://github.com/institut-de-genomique/Ultimate-DataTable/blob/a654711b0f35891ab70cc5f0df193f7671b42ad7/src/directives/udt-table.js#L35

Comment: Where do I have to put that code?? Could you be more specific and provide an example? Thanks!!!

Comment: This should be in your datatableConfig in UserHomeController

`var datatableConfig = {
                "name": "simple_datatable",
                "lines": {
                    "trClass" : function(data, line){
                        if(data.status ===1){
                            return "redCss";
                        }
                        return "defaultCss";
                    }
                },
                "columns": [

                    .....
            }`